# Reading value outside span tags in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, I am trying to get the text which is outside span
tags

```
<span>Source directory: </span>
"/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64"
<br>.
```

I want to get this value:

`/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64`

I am using xpath `/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/span[3]`, but it is giving output as : `Source directory:`

Can please someone suggest.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "get the text outside the source directory"? Selenium is used to scrape the Web not to go through a file system

Comment: Question is regarding scraping only and the source element is : < span >Source directory: < / span > "/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64"  <br> Since  /cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64 is not in any element , how to get the value?

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the _outerHTML_

Comment: I'm assuming the html that you posted is wrapped in a div or some other element. If so, then you can just get the text of the parent element and it will get return the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following XML to test it:

```
<root xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
    <actors>
        <actor id="1">Christian Bale</actor>
        <actor id="2">Liam Neeson</actor>
        <actor id="3">Michael Caine</actor>
    </actors>
    <foo:singers>
        <foo:singer id="4">Tom Waits</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="5">B.B. King</foo:singer>
        <foo:singer id="6">Ray Charles</foo:singer>
    </foo:singers>
<span>Source directory: </span>
"/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64"
</root>
```

and XPATH of

```
root/span/following-sibling::text()
```

results in

```
Text='
"/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64"
'
```

so it is more or less what you want.
I am not sure however, if this

```
/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/span[3]/following-sibling::text()
```

will be valid xpath expression in your case.

Comment: The basic concept is right but this won't work with Selenium because only XPath 1.0 is supported. He will either need to execute some JS to get what he wants or grab the `innerHTML` of the parent and parse the HTML down to what he wants.

Comment: @JeffC that is what I was suspecting, that this may not work in selenium.

Comment: @Antoniossss: /html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]/span[3]/following-sibling::text() , this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html looks something like this:

```
<div>
    <span>Source directory: </span>
    "/cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64"
    <br />
</div>
```

Using your xpath, you would select: `/html/body/div/div[4]/div[2]`
So, you have a WebElement that represent the parent div. When you call element.Text, you should get something like: `Source directory: /cs/orasoa/devtools/build/2353704573222573/A2B_LSP/RPMS/x86_64`

Side note:
I would very much suggest putting an ID on the element. The xpath that you have is extremely brittle as it relies on the entire page loading in a specific way. If someone adds a div above the current one, your test will not behave the same.